# Binaries for different compilers inside same gnu session or alternatives

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am having a design problem when using GNU Make. 
My problem is the following:

1. I have 2 executables to compile.
2. These binaries need to be compiled for each compiler I list in a variable, let us call it `COMPILERS`.
3. After compiling the binaries, I need to run all binaries (all of them) several times and generate, for each of them, the times in a text file.
4. I must put all these files together, and generate a plot out of all that data.

So, for example, if I have 3 compilers to test, I would have 6 binaries, 6 * n_of_time_to_run_benchmark and a final output with all that data, in a single plot file.

The problem with this is that my usual way to approach binary compilation is to use CXX variable, CXXFLAGS, etc. But the CXX variable is supposed to change inside the same session, which looks inconsistent to me. An example of invocation would be:

```
make plot COMPILERS=clang++ g++
```

What I did is to just compile binaries separately every time I invoke make and per compiler, making use of `CXX` variable.
From a script I create a folder `build-clang++` and compile, I create another folder `build-g++` and compile, run all benchmarks, per folder for every couple of executables for same compiler. But for this I need an external script, and this is what I want to avoid, to be able to port to windows later more easily without duplicating scripts or installing more dependencies.

What is the best way to handle this:

1. Use another Makefile that calls this makefile with different configurations and use it as my "script" for generating the plot? This way the makefile looks like much more traditional to me, with his separate flags, etc.
2. Just create all targets directly inside same Make session?

To me it looks cleaner the script solution because a Makefile is usually written in a way that the compiler is a fixed variable that does not change in the whole session.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use the solution I suggested to your previous question on the same topic?

Comment: Which parameter controls how many times you have to run the binaries and the differences between how the runs are executed? Or is that identical?

Comment: You seem confused about how `make` works. There is no such thing as a 'session', there is an acyclic graph of steps (recipes) that are executed. As I indicated in your previous question, you can give variables target-specific values and you can use this to set `$(CXX)` etcetera. You can also use `$(CXX)` as part of a target or dependency. So `make` really doesn't put any obstacles in your way.

Comment: Renaud: I am not still convinced wether that is the right way to do it. Seems odd to me still.

Comment: @reinerpost By session I mean to invoke a new make process from within make. Sorry for the bad terminology. What I do not get is how can I compile inside the same make execution with two different values for variable $(CXX) unless I misunderstood something before.

Comment: Simple: if you declare a make target `foo` and associate a value for variable `CXX` to this target, then, when make will build your target it will use that value of `CXX`. So if you write: `foo: CXX=g++`, then, when make will build `foo`, CXX will have value `g++`, even if you gave it another value elsewhere. Sorry to insist but you should really consider my previous answer. It does work and it is the make way.

Comment: I understand. Yes, I think it is a good solution.